# Fontconfig for iOS

Tags: ios, fontconfig

I download the Fontconfig-2.9.0.tar.gz from here http://freedesktop.org/software/fontconfig/release

but I don't know how to cross compiling it for iOS. I need a fontconfig.a for iOS, can somebody tell me how to compiling it or give me a guide?    thanks!

Answer (score 0):

./configure --host=arm-ios --prefix=$PREFIX --with-freetype-config=$PREFIX/bin/freetype-config --with-arch=arm
make
make install

Comment: I do this:   ./configure --host=arm-ios --prefix=/Users/bluefish625/Desktop/fontconfig/prefix/ --with-freetype-config=$PREFIX/bin/freetype-config --with-arch=arm.  then,failed reports: checking build system type... x86_64-apple-darwin11.3.0
checking host system type... Invalid configuration `arm-ios': system `ios' not recognized
configure: error: /bin/sh ./config.sub arm-ios failed

Comment: I try this: ./configure CC="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang" CFLAGS="-isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS5.1.sdk -arch armv7" --sysconfdir=/Users/bluefish625/Desktop/fontconfig/sysconfdir/ --prefix=/Users/bluefish625/Desktop/fontconfig/prefix/ --mandir=/Users/bluefish625/Desktop/fontconfig/mandir --disable-shared --host=armv7-apple-darwin --with-freetype-config=$PREFIX/bin/freetype-config

Comment: .The eror info is:configure: error: The pkg-config script could not be found or is too old.  Make sure it is in your PATH or set the PKG_CONFIG environment variable to the full
path to pkg-config.

Comment: have you resolved the above issue if yes please tell me how to do @Magicfish